# QGIS geometry generator - chainage nodes and labels along line at ellipsoidical distance

Tags: qgis

All points along line solution proposed in other question or plugin or processing toolbox use projected distance and not ellipsoidal.

I work with very long lines and is quite important that the points along line are based on ellipsoidal measures and not projected/plane.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried the two chainage plugins (pgChainage and QChainage), and the plugin Locate points along lines?

Comment: I've tried qchainage, locate point along lines and both use projected distance.

Comment: [Shape Tools](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/) has `Geodesic densifier`.

Comment: but what I understood is that Shape Tools densify a line by an integer number, I need to add markers every fixed geodetic distance (e.g every 1km).